# Как вывести информацию в всплывающем окне с пробелами

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Документ</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- hide
function first() {
// создает выпадающее окно, где размещается 
// текст, введенный в поле формы
valid = true;

        if ( (document.myForm.name.value == " ") || 
             (document.myForm.surname.value == " ") || 
             (document.myForm.fullname.value == " ") || 
             (document.myForm.doll.value == " ") || 
             (document.myForm.mes.value == " ") || 
             (document.myForm.telll.value == " " ) || 
             (document.myForm.dates.value == " " ) || 
             (document.myForm.blas.value == " " )  )
        {
                alert ( "Пожалуйста заполните все поля" );
                valid = false;
        }


    alert("Текст: " +  document.myForm.name.value +  
                   document.myForm.surname.value + 
                   document.myForm.fullname.value + 
                   document.myForm.doll.value +
                   document.myForm.mes.value +
                   document.myForm.telll.value +
                   document.myForm.dates.value + 
                   document.myForm.blas.value
                   );
                   return valid; 
};

// -->
</script>
<style>
input {
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    }
P {
    margin:10px 0 0 0 ;
    padding:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor=green>
<div class="outline">
<h1 align="center">Форма сотрудников библиотеки</h1>
</div>
<form name="myForm">
<p><img src="book.png" alt="Альтернативный текст" width="100" height="80" /></p>
<p><input style="color:red" type="text" align="center" name="name" id="names" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^а-яА-Я]/gi, '')"> Введите имя<br></p>
<input type="text" align="center" name="surname"  id="surnames" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^а-яА-Я]/gi, '')"> Введите фамилию<br>
<input type="text" align="center" align="center" color="black" name="fullname" id="fullnames" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^а-яА-Я]/gi, '')"> Введите отчество<br>
<input type="text" align="center" name="doll" placeholder="Специальность" id="dol" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^а-яА-Я]/gi, '')"> Укажите специальность<br>
<input type="tel" align="center" name="telll" id="tell" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^1-90]/gi, '')"> Телефон<br>
<input type="text" align="center" name="doll" id="mes" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^а-яА-Я]/gi, '')"> Город<br>
<input list="character" name="blas" id="bla" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^1-90]/gi, '')"> Стаж работы
<datalist id="character">
<option value="5 лет">
<option value="6 лет">
<option value="7 лет">
<option value="8 лет">
<option value="9 лет">
<option value="10 лет">
</datalist><br>

<input type="date"  name="dates" placeholder="Дата принятия на работу">Дата принятия на работу</p>

<input type="button" name="OK" value="ВСЕ ВЕРНО"
  onClick="first()">
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не ясна суть вашего вопроса. Расскажите о своей проблеме более развёрнуто

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы вывелись пробелы - их надо добавить в выводимую строку, например так:

```
 alert("Текст: " +  document.myForm.name.value + " " + 
                    document.myForm.surname.value + " " +
 ...
```

Либо воспользоваться [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
 alert(`Текст: ${document.myForm.name.value} ${document.myForm.surname.value} ...`)
```

Либо использовать [метод join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
 alert(["Текст: ", document.myForm.name.value
                 , document.myForm.surname.value
        ...
       ].join(' '));
```

Еще вариант - пробежаться в цикле по нужным элементам и собрать нужную строку.

Answer (score 0):

Добовляем в код "\n". 
Это лучше чем проблелы , а для пробелов добавьте - " " пробел.

```
alert("Текст: " +  document.myForm.name.value + "\n" +  
                   document.myForm.surname.value + "\n" + 
                   document.myForm.fullname.value + "\n" + 
                   document.myForm.doll.value + "\n" +
                   document.myForm.mes.value + "\n" +
                   document.myForm.telll.value + "\n" +
                   document.myForm.dates.value + "\n" + 
                   document.myForm.blas.value
                   );
                   return valid; 
};
```